# How to get trace id and span id in the log4j2, in the format [traceId, spanId ]?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, trace, spring-cloud-sleuth

How to get trace id and span id in the log4j2, not the in the [traceId, spanId ] ?

Expected Output :
[APPNAME,5a59b2372d9a3814,5a59b2372d9a3814]

Actual Output :
[logLevel=ERROR] -- 2021-01-21 11:30:32,489 +0530 -- http-nio-8080-exec-1 com.springboot.test.aspect.MyAspect -- asnId= - message="Logging key:", traceId=f19556b82d98bf86, executionTimeSeconds=23

My log4j2 : tried adding below commented property but not seeing trace id in logs

```
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">[logLevel=%-5p] -- %d %d{Z} -- %t %c -- asnId=%X{ASN} - %m%n</Property>
        <property name="log.level">${bundle:DEV:logLevel}</property>
         <!--  <property name="rolling.file.encoder.pattern"
              value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %-5level : loggerName=&quot;%logger{36}&quot; threadName=&quot;%thread&quot;  appName=&quot;${springAppName:-}&quot; trace=&quot;%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}&quot; span=&quot;%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}&quot; spanName=&quot;%X{X-Span-Name:-}&quot; parent=&quot;%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId:-}&quot; exportable=&quot;%X{X-Span-Export:-}&quot; pid=&quot;${PID:-}&quot; txnId=&quot;%X{txnId}&quot; %msg%n"/> -->
         <!--   <property name="PATTERN" value="%h %l %u [%date{dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSS}] &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot; &quot;%i{User-Agent}&quot; [trace=%responseHeader{X-B3-TraceId},span=%i{X-B3-SpanId}] %D"/> -->
    </Properties>
```

Aspect class :

In the log of my Aspect class however I can see the trace id

```
public class MyAspect {

    private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyAspect.class);
    long startTime = new Date().getTime();
    
    @Autowired
    Tracer tracer;

      @Around("allControllerMethods() && args(..,@annotation(org.springframework...RequestBody) requestBody) ")
      public Object controllerEvents(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, Object requestBody) throws Throwable {
            
         ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
             HttpServletRequest request = attributes.getRequest();
             MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) jp.getSignature();
              Method method = signature.getMethod();
              Object resObject = jp.proceed();
         
              logger.error("traceId", tracer.currentSpan().context().traceIdString());

        }
    }
```

pom :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
            <artifactId>brave</artifactId>
            <version>5.12.6</version>
        </dependency> 
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

ConfigHandler :

```
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
```

Please see that in the test project where I am not using log4j it comes as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get the traceId and spanId by making below changes :
1)Add to log4j

```
  <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">[logLevel=%-5p]-- [%X{traceId}/%X{spanId}] -- %d %d{Z} -- %t %c - %m%n</Property>
```

2)Add property :

```
request.logging.shouldLog=true
```

3)Add

```
    @Value("${request.logging.shouldLog}")
    private boolean shouldLog;
    
//    @Override
    protected boolean shouldLog(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return shouldLog;
    }
```